# Adding a calculated field with data from another table

Tags: atk4

So I have a model `site(#id, name, start_date, end_date)` which might be in `pause(#id, site_id, start_date, end_date)` and I want to keep track of pauses.

I started by adding an expander button in the site CRUD to be able to add/remove pauses. Works like a charm.

But now I would like to know directly in the site list the state of each. So I started by adding a new expression field and just test if the site is in progress or not:

`$this->addExpression('state')->set('if(site.end_date IS NULL,"In Progress", if(now() < site.end_date, "In Progress", "Ended"))');`

Works perfectly ! But now I can't think of the method to determine if the site is in pause or not and in fact I cannot reproduice the result above using `addExpression()->set(function($m, $q) {});`

Edit:

So the example given by DarkSide works like a charm, still I need now to mix the two result into an only field `state`:

```
$this->addExpression('state')->set(function($model, $select)
 {
   // Is it ended ?
   $ended = $select->expr('if(site.date_ended IS NULL,"In Progress", if(now() < site.date_ended, "In Progress", "Ended"))');

   // Is it in pause ?
   $paused = $model->refSQL('Site_Pause')
                   ->count()
                   ->where('date_started', '<', $select->expr('now()'))
                   ->where('date_ended', '>', $select->expr('now()'));

  if ($paused > 0)
    return 'paused';
  return $ended;
 });
```

As $model->refSQL() returns a DSQL Object I cannot use of `if` statements. Should I try to make a all in once SQL query or try like above to use `if` statements by getting the results from Dsql object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it ! I post here the solution if needed by anyone:

`$this->addExpression('etat')->set(function($model, $select)
{
  return (
    $select->expr(
      'IF (
           site.date_ended IS NULL OR NOW() < site.date_ended,
           IF (
               [f1] > 0,
               "Paused",
               "In Progress"
           ),
           "Ended"
      )'
    )->setCustom('f1',
                 $model->refSQL('Site_Pause')
                       ->count()
                       ->where('date_started', '<', $select->expr('NOW()'))
                       ->where('date_ended', '>', $select->expr('NOW()'))
    )
  );
});`

Answer (score 0):

**In Model_Site:**

*Bad example:*

I guess You can add everything in subselect in set() method as expression, but that's nor nice nor advisable.

```
$this->addExpression('paused')
    ->set("if( (SELECT 1 FROM pause WHERE pause.start_date<now() AND (pause.end_date IS NULL OR pause.end_date>now())), 'yes', 'no') ");
```

*Better example:*

```
$this->addExpression('paused')->set(function($m, $q){
    return $m->refSQL('Pause') // Model_Pause
        ->where('start_date', '<', $q->expr('now()'))
        ->where('end_date', '>', $q->expr('now()')) // here you'll also need to use q->orExpr() to add case when end_date is null (see expression above in bad example)
        ->count()
        ;
);
```

Something like this you can see in my Scheduler add-on Models (last_status, last_run, next_status, next_run in Model_Task). Here is link: https://github.com/DarkSide666/ds-addons/tree/master/Scheduler/lib/Model/Scheduler

*Please keep in mind, that all examples above are completely untested and are here just to give you idea.*

Comment: Thx I better understand now the use of $m and $q, see edited question for the final step I'd like to achieve

Comment: I think You should try to make all in one SQL and then return it as DSQL. You can try to inject one DSQL into another DSQL as subselect. Maybe that can help. Tonight I'm a bit to sleepy to make good example of that :)